# How to hide disabled input underline style

Tags: css, input, polymer, disabled-input, text-decorations

When styling an HTML element like `paper-input` and `disabled` a dotted underline style is added.

[image]

I can edit the disabled styles like

```
paper-input {
  --paper-input-container-disabled: {
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
  };
}
```

But setting the `text-decoration` does not hide this style.

How can I set the CSS to hide this `disabled` underline style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the display: none property to remove the underline.

```
 <style is="custom-style">
      :root {
        --paper-input-container-underline: {
          display: none;
        };
      }
    </style>
```

Try removing the root if It doesn't work for you.